# Android Studio default New Project Wizard Missing

Tags: android, setup-project

I closed my android studio. Opened it the following day and the default simple new project wizard window was gone, instead its a lousy NewProject dialogbox/ wizard with java, gradle, groovy, griffon, static web, & empty project options on the left. I dont want this, the simple new project dialog/ wizard we all know with startup templates is gone. Please help, how do I get it back?

Answer (score 8):

Solved by OP:

> You must enable the Android Support. Plugin Configuration > Plugin > Android Support Plugin. Make sure its checked!

Answer (score 2):

I tried for 1 hour, but wasting a lot of time. You can reset the Android Studio to default by only deleting the `.AndroidStudio` folder.

This way Android Studio will be reset. This fixed the issue for me.

**NOTE:** Before going ahead be aware of your old projects and create a backup.

Answer (score 0):

If the Plugin > Android Support Plugin is already checked, then uncheck it, check it again. Now the android studio will display a popup asking to restart to apply the changes. Selecting to restart will reset the android configurations to the latest. If there was any missing SDK, android studio will ask to download it.

Now the **+ Start a new Android Studio project** will be displayed!

It worked for me and I hope it helps someone else. I suspect the problem was due to outdated or improper sdk configuration.